# Using composeResolvers with an array of resolvers

Tags: graphql, graphql-tools

Is it possible to pass an array of resolvers into composeResolvers from "@graphql-tools/resolvers-composition". If I do something like `composeResolvers(authorsResolvers, resolversComposition);` it works however if I try to pass in all my resolvers, `composeResolvers(resolvers, resolversComposition);`, it doesn't work.

```
const rootResolver = {};

const resolvers = [rootResolver, authorsResolvers, booksResolvers];

const isAuthenticated =
  () =>
  (next: any) =>
  async (root: any, args: any, context: any, info: any) => {
    if (!context.currentUser) {
      throw new Error("You are not authorized");
    }
    return next(root, args, context, info);
  };

const resolversComposition = {
  "*.*": [isAuthenticated()],
};

const composedResolvers = composeResolvers(resolvers, resolversComposition);

export default composedResolvers;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `composeResolvers` expects an object as the first argument.
If all valid resolver objects, you could do something like this:

```
const resolvers = {...rootResolver, ...authorsResolvers, ...booksResolvers};
```

But make sure to do the necessary adjustments in case they have overlapping attributes, otherwise the last one will override the former.